# TFS 2015 on-prem licensing issue on REST API

Tags: api, tfs

We have recently upgraded our TFS 2012 to TFS 2015 Update 1 and I would like to use the new TFS REST API to retrieve tests cases/plans for instance.

So I made a quick test with my browser using the following URL and everything went well : http://.../DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0

But when I tried to get the test plans in particular using that url : 
http://.../DefaultCollection/ProjectXYZ/_apis/test/plans?api-version=1.0

I obtained the following error :

`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Web-based Test Case Management","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.MissingLicenseException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"MissingLicenseException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

So how do I activate that "license" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved by following the following instructions : http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/tf400409-you-do-not-have-licensing-rights/

So basically I only had to set the "default access level" to advanced in the web control panel.

Comment: @GiulioVian I have to wait 2 days to do it :(